# From css to Javascript for input:focus {outline: none; }

Tags: javascript, css

I have a line of Javascript like this:

```
var d = document.createElement('input');
d.type = 'radio';
...
document.body.appendChild(d);
```

Since I don't want focus on it... I have added this line in the CSS

```
input:focus {outline: none; }
```

and it all works very nicely.#

The quesion is: 
How can I move that line of CSS in javascript ?

I am writing a Javascript library and I don't want to ship a CSS dependency ...

thanks

Note: the problem lies in the pseudo style stuff. How do I do that in js

Comment: Make it into a class and assign class to your element

Comment: You can always do `d.style.outline = 'none'` but what's wrong in including a CSS file with your plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change styles with Javascript like this:

```
document.getElementById("id").style.property="value"
```

In your case you can use d.style. and the property you want to change

Comment: Pseudo-stuff like `:focus` as well?

Comment: in this case: `d.style.outline = "none";`

Comment: how does this answer the question of targeting input:focus

Comment: The point is it doesn't need to apply this style on `:focus` pseudo-class.

Comment: yea I guess it doesn't need outline without focus